# Reset mysql server root password?

Tags: mysql

I do not care to gain access to any database data, I simply want to reset the root password for the MySQL server on an ubuntu 14.04 LTS vm that I am using for development and testing.

Several places I have read that dpkg-reconfigure will prompt for a new MySQL root password, but it does not. Nor does uninstalling and reinstalling mysql-server.

I tried uninstalling and zapping the configuration folder /etc/mysql, and that also had no effect.

It must have prompted me when I ran the installer and now I've forgotten what I entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest method (as the Ubuntu [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) suggests):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-N.N`

replace `N.N` with the version of MySql.

Comment: As I stated already, I have read that dpkg-reconfigure will prompt for a new MySQL root password, but it does not.  I ran that command (5.6 was the version I think). It had no effect and there was no prompt

Comment: did you try the other ('not-really-hard') options mentioned in the link?

Comment: Alternative `UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')` worked