# How can I reset mysql-server-8.0 root password on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mysql, 20.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and messed something up with MySQL. I don't know how to login:

```
$ mysql -u root -p                      
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I don't have any data in there, so I don't care if the DB is lost. In fact, I would prefer a clean solution.

### What I tried

#### dpkg-reconfigure

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/622343/10425):

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-8.0
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 7577
```

Finishes without an error message, but I don't see any way to enter a new password.

#### mysqld_safe

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036081/10425), but

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
$ ls -alh /var/run/mysqld/           
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root   40 Mai 17 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root  root 1,1K Mai 17 11:08 ..
```

I guess this might be an issue? What should I do?

#### Complete reinstall

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/172516/10425) to completely re-install mysql, but I run into the same issues.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu Server 20.04 for me

Comment: worked for me too, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was on the wrong track. I simply needed to login via

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
```

So **not** the `-p` option. No password required.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 defaults to using `auth_socket` instead of passwords for `root` user, which means after installing `mysql-server-8.0` you can simply login automatically with either:

```
sudo mysql
```

or

```
sudo mysql --user=root --host=localhost
```

...no need to specify the `root` user if you're already logged in as `root` to your shell. However if you are logged in as a different sudo user then you can specify that username instead (and no password) as long as the sudo user was added to MySQL as an `auth_socket` user.

The only time you need to specify a password if when logging in via TCP (e.g. @127.0.0.1). So if you try something like `sudo mysql --user=root --host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp` then MySQL will prompt you for a password... but unless you setup a root@127.0.0.1 (TCP) user and password then you will not be able to login using that method.

Keep in mind it is now highly recommend to not setup a root TCP user these days, and instead create an alternative "maintenance" user (e.g. for phpMyAdmin) like [admin@127.0.0.1](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/ss-install-mysql.txt).